# 0 is ignored when assigning value to cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string

Why when I do, `ActiveCell.Value = "1.10"`, I end up getting `ActiveCell.Value = 1.1`?

I would want that whatever is on the right side, which is a string type, would match exactly the content of the cell which I am assigning the value to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are handled as numbers and mathematically `1.10` and `1.1` is equal!

#### Handle 1.10 as text

If you use `'` before the number

```
ActiveCell.Value = "'1.10"
```

it forces Excel to handle it as text/string. Note that then you are not able to calculate with that anymore.

Alternative is setting the number format to taxt and then add the value

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveCell.Value = "1.10"
```

Or something like

```
Dim foo As Variant
foo = "1.10"

ActiveCell.Value = "'" & foo
```

#### Handle 1.1 as number but format it so it looks like 1.10

If you want it to be considered as a number (so you can calculate with it) and still make it look like a 2 digit decimal then use

```
ActiveCell.Value = "1.1"
```

and format it correctly

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "#.00"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about if I do ActiveCell.Value = foo, foo being "1.10" and I still want to keep the zero?

Comment: @Kronax see my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I needed ;)

Comment: @BigBen Yes and no. Because Excel always *"thinks"* and interprets: `ActiveCell.Value = "1.10"` will result in a numeric value in the cell (as long as number format is not set to text). That means if you eg. get the `"1.10"` from a text box (it is a string) and will automatically convert into a number. And that actually is the issue the OP has and what I tried to refer to here. We write a string into a cell and Excel converts it into a number (the downside of having implicit type conversions).